# APT::Default-Release "stable" isn't sufficient to stop packages being automatically upgraded after adding another repository

Tags: debian, apt

*Note: At the time I wrote this question (and answer), Debian Stable was **buster**, and Debian Testing was **bullseye***.

I'm using Debian Stable, and I want to install a newer version of a package - it's available in Debian Testing.

Conventional wisdom suggests the the procedure for doing this is

1. Add the relevant `deb` lines to `/etc/sources.list`

```
deb     http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main non-free
```

2. To prevent all your packages being upgraded, you should create or modify `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and put this line in it:

```
APT::Default-Release "buster";
```

And then I can install the one specific package by using the `apt install -t testing packagename`.

---

However, despite adding the `Default-Release` directive, my system still offers several updates when I run:
`apt update`.

How can I prevent these updates from being installed when I run `apt upgrade` as part of normal system maintenance?

Answer (score 6):

The packages causing the problem have been installed or upgraded from the [`stable-updates`](https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates) release.

The `Default-Release` directive only increases the priority for the `stable` release, so the newly added `testing` repository has the same priority as `stable-updates`, and because the version number is higher, the one from `testing` will be installed.

This also has the side-effect that future versions published in `stable-updates` would not be installed because you've told apt that the `stable` release is preferred.

You can investigate where the versions offered come from and their priority using `apt-cache policy [packagename]`.

---

The better way of doing this is to use **Apt-Pinning**.

First, remove the `APT::Default-Release "buster";` line from `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (or delete the whole file if if that's the only thing in it).

Create or modify `/etc/apt/preferences` and add the following lines:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=bullseye
Pin-Priority: 50
```

This looks at any package (the `*`) in a release called `bullseye`, and assigns a priority of 50.

This is lower than value for installed packages (100) - so it won't upgrade you system even if it can find a newer verison in `bullseye`.

It's also lower that the value for non-installed packages in other repositories (500) - so you can still upgrade packages when they become available, but it will prefer the newest version in the old repositories instead of the newest version is `bullseye`. (Have a look at the [relevant section of the Debian handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html#sect.apt.priorities) for more detail.)

Now you can run `apt update` and `apt ugprade` without changing anything unexpectedly.

---

NB: On my system I still have two packages offered for upgrade - theses were thanks to a system installed preferences file that had pinned two security updates, which I was okay with.